# PHP - create multiple tables

Tags: php

I'm creating an installation page where the new user enters their database host, username, host and password. I have this done and it's working.

I need to make it so it creates a table.

I know how to do it but not with my whole sql export.

I need to insert my whole sql export into their database.

I'm getting an error on the line with online_users but I am not sure why.

My sql export is :

```
          $sql = "
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS failed (
            cpukey varchar(32) NOT NULL,
            ip varchar(30) NOT NULL,
            kvdata blob
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS online_users (
            session char(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            time int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            username varchar(255) NOT NULL
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

          INSERT INTO online_users (session, time, username) VALUES
          ('s9p65g909gg9l6qh7dtr947hp4', 1500315177, 'BenzaHdd');


          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS serversettings (
            freemode tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            bypasses tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
            id int(255) NOT NULL,
            port int(10) NOT NULL,
            token varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            listener_ip text NOT NULL,
            LogLocation varchar(255) NOT NULL
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

          INSERT INTO serversettings (freemode, bypasses, id, port, token, listener_ip, LogLocation) VALUES
          (1, 1, 1, 52, '675DFE06DC49999AE153815BD9A8818B', '192.168.0.1', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ampps\\www\\configuration\\log\\console.log');

          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sitesettings (
            site_name varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TeamXerone',
            team_motto varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'The Art of Modding',
            site_url varchar(999) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'http://localhost/XBL/',
            id int(255) NOT NULL
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

          INSERT INTO sitesettings (site_name, team_motto, site_url, id) VALUES
          ('ProjectBenza', 'Generation Infinite', 'http://localhost', 1);

          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tokens (
            id int(11) NOT NULL,
            user_id varchar(999) NOT NULL,
            token varchar(300) NOT NULL,
            generate_by varchar(99) NOT NULL,
            used int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            used_by varchar(99) DEFAULT NULL,
            time_generated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            durability int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 = 1 day | 1 = 7 days | 2 = 14 days | 3 = 31 days | 4 = 3 months | 5 = 6 months | 6 = year | 7 = lifetime'
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=90 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

          INSERT INTO tokens (id, user_id, token, generate_by, used, used_by, time_generated, durability) VALUES
          (71, 'BenzaHdd', 'ABC-123-45X', 'BenzaHdd', 0, NULL, '2017-07-15 17:54:01', 99),
          (83, 'BenzaHdd', '58PN-756MV0-0YFN', 'BenzaHdd', 0, NULL, '2017-07-15 19:49:32', 1),
          (89, 'Client', 'LEJU-GAR008-EBOJ', 'BenzaHdd', 0, NULL, '2017-07-15 20:11:38', 99);

          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS updates (
            id int(99) NOT NULL,
            title varchar(99) DEFAULT NULL,
            description varchar(999) DEFAULT NULL,
            postedBy varchar(99) DEFAULT NULL,
            timePosted datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

          INSERT INTO updates (id, title, description, postedBy, timePosted) VALUES
          (1, 'Launch of backend', 'This is the launch of my super advanced backend I have been working on for many, many months. I have finally decided to launch a stable and advanced version of this backend and will continue to add more and more as I think of new ideas. Prices will be shown in my skype mood.', 'Admin', '2016-12-14 21:05:54');

          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id int(11) NOT NULL,
            username varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User',
            password varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Client',
            email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
            cpukey varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
            salt varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
            ip varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '127.0.0.1',
            time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
            titleid text NOT NULL,
            enabled tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            kvdata blob,
            lastonline datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            profile_picture varchar(999) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'images/default.jpg',
            userLevel int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            register_time datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            customlifetimenotify varchar(40) DEFAULT 'XboxPal - Change your notify on our site',
            gamertag varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None'
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=88 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

          INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, email, cpukey, salt, ip, time, titleid, enabled, kvdata, lastonline, profile_picture, userLevel, register_time, customlifetimenotify, gamertag) VALUES
          (71, 'BenzaHdd', '$2y$10$Of8OZoXuZOwYIN65Yr1vPOQlCigAByxXmqvDd.GZQvWppBlQckq5W', 'benzaofficial55@gmail.com', 'D31E025FF263E0B8AED87052BA86E51D', NULL, '94.9.19.252', '2018-08-29 00:00:02', '', 1, NULL, '2017-07-09 18:24:11', '../uploads/635933476972091420917241652_bl.jpg', 3, '2017-04-06 12:53:28', 'Ben is a fucking boss', 'None'),
          (72, 'Benny', '$2y$10$2ojCm39w45NAONn0.XqeLeHyElC/7yyRVCnvxjKVo1kAkPNQ3I6XG', 'benza@hotmail.com', '99999999999999999999999999999999', NULL, '204.13.204.125', '2018-07-06 00:00:00', '', 1, NULL, '2017-07-08 19:27:57', '../uploads/myAvatar black back.png', 0, '2017-07-18 00:00:00', 'Ben is a fucking god.', 'None'),
          (73, 'TomGydey', '$2y$10$qnPbhfH0RbXmRi8RZ1RNKedVdqiYTPdUsg4GDK/5vhhA.DI2lmer2', 'test@hotmail.com', '99999999999999999999999999999999', NULL, '79.67.114.16', '2018-07-01 00:00:00', '', 1, NULL, '2017-07-07 13:24:25', 'http://ya-techno.com/forum/images/icons/myIcons/red-xbox-256.png', 0, '2017-07-07 11:54:49', 'XboxPal - Change your notify on our site', 'None'),
          (85, '', 'Client', '', '', NULL, '127.0.0.1', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', 0, NULL, '2017-07-17 18:37:11', 'images/default.jpg', 0, '2017-07-17 18:37:11', '', 'None');
      ";

      if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
          echo "Table created successfully.";
      } else{
          echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);
      }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @AdamA `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS online_users ( session char(100) NOT' at line 8`

Comment: So you login to someone elses database and run queries on their database to create your tables? This sounds like a horrible security practice. Plus not to mention that hosts shouldn't allow mysql to be remotely accessible (either only accessible via localhost or on a private internal lan so it can be only accessed by the servers on their network). Which means your script wouldn't work on many hosts (or really shouldn't).

Comment: Benza, I tried your create table script and it worked perfectly for me. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Difster try it within php, not phpmyadmin.

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bc896. I would assume the user account doesn't have access to create new tables. They likely need to use a control panel or elevated account to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have multiple queries in your `$sql` string.

Change `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` to `mysqli_multi_query($con, $sql)` and all will be fine.